# How to calculate the trainable param quantity to be 335872 in this LSTM sample code?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I got this sample code but can't figure out how to calculate the trainable parameters to be 335872? (showed in the following output)

I would appreciate it if anyone could help on this question. Thanks!

-------------------------code------------------------------------

```
input_shape = (None, num_encoder_tokens)

# Define an input sequence and process it.
  encoder_inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
  encoder = LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True)
  encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder(encoder_inputs)

# We discard `encoder_outputs` and only keep the states.
  encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

  encoder_model = Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_states)
  encoder_model.summary(line_length=100)

  encoder_model.output_shape
```

---------------------output is as follows----------------------

---

```
Layer (type)           Output Shape                      Param #        
=================================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)   (None, None, 71)                        0              
_________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_5 (LSTM)     [(None, 256), (None, 256), (None, 256)] 335872         
=================================================================================
Total params: 335,872
Trainable params: 335,872
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________________________
[(None, 256), (None, 256)]
```

Comment: can you tell the values of `latent_dim` and `num_encoder_tokens`.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to know how to train the model so that `weight matrices`, `biases`, etc. can be calculated.

The problem with your code is that you have only defined the architecture of your model. You haven't really compiled it. Do this in the end:

`encoder_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics='binary_accuracy')`

In the above line of code, `loss`, `optimizer` and `metrics` is up to you to choose depending on the type of your problem.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro could you please edit the question? I could not figure out the meaning of "trainable parameters as 335872" so I assumed the author wants to know about training the parameters.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I have modified the question and make it clearer.

Comment: My question is that why the quantity of Trainable params is 335,872? 

you could see that the output of the code includes:
Trainable params: 335,872